# MySQL 2 columns index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have **unique** index on 2 columns: `name`(varchar) and `add_date`(date).
If i add **non unique** indexes on `name` and on `add_date` its increase select speed or not?
`name` and `add_date` apart may not be unique.
**UPD**
MySQL console `show columns` says:
`| Field   | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

| name    | varchar(10)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |

| time    | date                | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will speed if you selecting on each one separately.

but make sure you need it.

Comment: Yeah, I need it, thanks for answer.  Actually I need only select from `add_date` and I add index to this column.

Comment: which is the first column of the joined index ? is add_date is just date of DateTime (in that case it will almost surly be unique...)

Comment: The first is `name`. I update answer to show type of columns.

Comment: Need I to add index to `add_date` column or not? Its content adding without miliseconds, just only year, month, day, hour, minute, second...